# Use backup file from dd to restore hard disk and also extract files

Tags: partition, dd, restore

I made regular complete backups of my hard disk (with all partitions) using `dd` tool as `backup.img` file. I have several such files.

Now that my old hard disk died, how can I use `backup.img` file to write on a new hard disk so that I have all the partitions and file intact as in the image.

Also is it possible to extract some part of data (few files/folders) from such file `backup.img`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Restore

You can restore the image back to your replacement HDD with something along the lines of:

```
# dd if=backup.img of=/dev/sd?
```

You will end up with a clone of your original disk including all partitions and data.

The downside to this is that the partitions won't be resized by `dd` so your replacement disk must be identical to or larger in capacity than the original.

If you're happy with that you can use a bootable image that contains `gparted` or similar (such as Parted Magic) and resize the partitions to fit the new disk.

## Mounting

To mount the image you'll need to use `losetup`.

### Older Method

The older way to do this is by calculating the offset to the start of the partition, as follows:

Run `fdisk` and look for the sector size:

```
# fdisk -l backup.img
Disk backup.img: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x91999386

Device      Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
backup.img1 *       2048  1026047  1024000  500M 83 Linux
backup.img2      1026048 16777215 15751168  7.5G 8e Linux LVM
```

to calculate your offset, read the *Start* column for the partition you're interested in and multiply that value by your sector size.  For example, to read `backup.img1` above, multiply 2048 x 512 = 1048576.

Use this value as the offset for `losetup` as follows:

```
# losetup -o 1048576 /dev/loop0 backup.img
```

then mount the loopback device:

```
# mount -t ext4 /dev/loop0 /mnt
```

### Later Method

Newer versions of `losetup` will scan and automatically create `/dev/loop` entries for all partitions in the image, as follows:

```
# losetup -Pf backup.img
# ls /dev/loop0*
/dev/loop0  /dev/loop0p1  /dev/loop0p2
# mount -t ext4 /dev/loop0p1 /mnt
```

### LVM Partitions

My example above shows the second partition as LVM.  To extract files from these, simply allow LVM to do it's magic on the loopback device.  First scan:

```
# pvs
  PV           VG            Fmt  Attr PSize PFree 
  /dev/loop0p2 fedora-server lvm2 a--  7.51g 40.00m
```

then activate the VG (note the VG name from the above command, yours will probably be different to mine):

```
# vgchange -a y fedora-server
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "fedora-server" now active
```

check what partitions you have:

```
# ls /dev/fedora-server/
root  swap
```

and mount one of them:

```
# mount -t ext4 /dev/fedora-server/root /mnt
```

### Exit

Once you've extracted the files:

```
# umount /mnt
# losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

or for LVM mounts:

```
# umount /mnt
# vgchange -a n fedora-server
  0 logical volume(s) in volume group "fedora-server" now active
# losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Comment: More recent versions of `mount` understand the `loop` option to set up a loop device for you and remove it on unmounting, e. g.: `mount -o loop backup.img /mnt`

Comment: @DavidFoerster - With partitions within the image? I've just tried that on Arch (util-linux 2.28) and it failed :-(

Comment: Oh, you're right. I missed the part of the question in parentheses about the image being of the entire disk. Nevermind then.

Comment: If you don't have `losetup -P` you still might not have to do manual offset calculation — just do `losetup` followed by `kpartx -a`. Should work on most systems under 10 years old.